# Getting an empty XML response from the HttpGet Entity object

Tags: java, javascript, xml, servlets, http-get

I have developed a JAVA web application which executes the HTTP Get request and receives the response from the server in xml form.

*home.jsp* is sending an AJAX request to servlet via

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","GetResponse?operation=" + operation,true);
```

and on the servlet whose response content type is *text/xml* we're performing the HttpGet operation with

```
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStr);
response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
response.getEntity();
```

The content of entity through stream sometimes its giving *HTTP/1.1 200 OK* with proper reponse i.e.

```
<Dialogs>
  <Dialog>
    <associatedDialogUri></associatedDialogUri>
  </Dialog>
</Dialogs>
```

and control is returning back to jsp's javascript with the xml.

The problem is if I'll make the same operation again it'll give *HTTP/1.1 200 OK* but response as

```
<Dialogs/>
```

I've checked the same with Poster plugin of Firefox.